# General solution for the two-body problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am trying to compare numerical solutions of the two-body problem with the analytical one. But, for some reason, the analytical one doesn't seem to agree with the numerical one. For the numerical method, I use Euler's method (even though I have way more sophisticated methods) to calculate the two bodies pretty accurately. For the analytical solution, I use the following equations (derived from this paper : [https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dbski/writings/twobody.pdf](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Edbski/writings/twobody.pdf))

$r_{1}(\theta) = \frac{L^2}{K(1+e\,\cos(\theta-\theta_{0})}$
and
$r_{2}(\theta) = -\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}\frac{L^2}{K(1+e\,\cos(\theta-\theta_{0})}$

Where the constants $L, K, e, \alpha,u_{0},r_{0}$ are given, according to the paper, by

$L = r_{0}u_{0}\sin(\alpha)$

$K = \frac{Gm_{1}^2m_{2}}{(m_{1}+m_{2})^2}$

$e = \sqrt{\left(\frac{r_{0}u_{0}^2\sin^2(\alpha)}{K}-1\right)^2 + \frac{r_{0}^2u_{0}^4\cos^2(\alpha)}{K^2}}$

$\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{vy_{1}-\frac{m_{1}vy_{1}+m_{2}vy_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}{vx_{1}-\frac{m_{1}vx_{1}+m_{2}vx_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}\right)$

$u_{0} = \sqrt{\left(vx_{1}-\frac{m_{1}vx_{1}+m_{2}vx_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}\right)^2+\left(vy_{1}-\frac{m_{1}vy_{1}+m_{2}vy_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}\right)^2}$

$r_{0} = \sqrt{\left(x_{1}-\frac{m_{1}x_{1}+m_{2}x_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}\right)^2+\left(y_{1}-\frac{m_{1}y_{1}+m_{2}y_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}\right)^2}$

Plugging in the values for a certain initial condition, I do find a trajectory, although it is not even close to the trajectory obtained by numerical means. Hopefully, if one of you could help me find out the mistake here, it would be gladly appreciated. I would like to add that the numerical method is not the problem here, because it has been verified with several other more sophisticated methods.

Comment: The angle $\theta$, or true anomaly, is not equal to time, or mean anomaly. They need to be translated into each other, mean to eccentric via the Kepler equation and eccentric to true via the half-angle tangent relations. For elliptic orbits both are monotonous, but non-linear bijective functional relations. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461290/proving-keplers-second-law-in-a-different-way/4066571#4066571 and https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40700/solving-keplers-equation-with-newton-raphson-method

Comment: Or staying local: [search for eccentric anomaly etc.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=anomaly+mean+true+eccentric)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange.

When asking a question on a Forum, you must ensure you give your readers all the tools to answer it . How do you expect anyone to help you find the error if you do not post the details of **BOTH** methods.

Euler's method is unstable. Use a more refined integration method. The [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) integration algorithm is kind of a workhorse to always start with.

The Kepler problem has 7 conserved quantities:

- The angular momentum: $\vec{L} $
- The energy: E
- The [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector): $ A$

When you numerically integrate a system that you know have constant of motions, it is a good idea to check they remain constant through time.

I suggest that you come back and post again your question with the graph of the evolution in time of these 7 quantities.

Comment: I can assure you with 100% confidence that the numerical methods are fine. I have several other methods like a 5th order symplectic method or a N order Taylor series. I only use Euler's method because it is blazing fast and gives quick and accurate results. I know for a fact that the problem lies in the analytic solution or something wrong I did while manipulating the analytical solution. (Although I am pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with my manipulations because I was just following the papers instructions). Anyways, providing proof that my NM works will not solve the problem.

Comment: Errors origin can be very stupid looking. You missed a parenthesis, the angles are in degrees, instead of radian, etc.
Use another integrating method to eliminate the instability hypothesis. If you find the same result, the origin of the discrepancy is elsewhere.

Graph the seven conserved quantities, you will get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a "check my work" question! The physics is correct, so the answer is that you are doing something wrong. The easiest places to go wrong are:

1. An issue using $tan^{-1}$ (in programming, it is almost always better to use `atan2(y,x)` which returns an angle in a full $360^\circ$ range).
2. Calculating $\theta_0$ incorrectly. I find this a particularly annoying step!
3. Getting the inverse transformation incorrect. eg, maybe your transform $(x_1,y_1,v_{x1},v_{y1},x_2,y_2,v_{x2},v_{y2})\mapsto (L,K,e,\theta,\theta_0,\ldots)$ is correct, but the inverse transformation you're comparing with your Euler integration is incorrect.

I happen to have a working implementation for a fixed central body, described below. Maybe the source code will be of help for you. The two body problem solution is just a transformation of the one body problem.

---

We have a unit mass particle at angle $\phi$ with respect to the central body, angular momentum $M$, distance $r$ from the center, orbital energy $E$, where $p$ and $e$ are the semilatus rectum and eccentricity of the ellipse, and the particle
is in a potential $-k/r$. Then we have:

$$p=\frac{M^2}{k}$$
$$e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2 E M^2}{k^2}}$$
$$r(\varphi)=\frac{p}{1+e\cos(\varphi-\varphi_0)}$$
$$\dot{\varphi}=\frac{M}{r^2}$$
$$\varphi_0=\varphi-\mbox{ArcTanFull}\left(\frac{\dot{r} p}{M e} ,(\frac{p}{r}-1)\frac{1}{e}\right)$$

In a Javascript implementation, here is how I initialize particles given an input position and velocity:

```
var k=4; //G*Mass
var scaleval=100; //scale for drawing.
var particlelist=[];
var newParticle=function(x,y,velx,vely){
    var x2=(x-200)/scaleval; //200 is the location of the fixed mass in my coordinates. Scaling is just done for drawing purposes.
    var y2=(y-200)/scaleval;
    var r=sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2);
    var E=-k/r+0.5*(velx*velx+vely*vely);
    var M=x2*vely-y2*velx;
    var ecc=sqrt(1+2*E*M*M/(k*k));
    var par=M*M/k;
    var phi=atan2(y2,x2);
    var tmp=atan2((x2*velx+y2*vely)*par/(M*ecc*r),(par/r-1)/ecc);
    
    var phi0=atan2(y2,x2)-tmp;
    return {phi:phi,phi0:phi0,E:E,eccentricity:ecc,parameter:par,M:M};
};
//Particles are drawn at angle phi and radius //r=p.parameter/(1+p.eccentricity*cos(phi-p.phi0));
```

Later in the code, timestepping is done through the Euler method and the ODE $\dot\phi=M/r^2$.

Implementations:

https://www.mathandcode.com/kepler/

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/kepler-orbits/4851061590900736 (be warned: Khan Academy outputs degrees from its inverse trig functions, and expects degrees into its trig functions)
[image: Plot of several kepler orbits in the apps]

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I was certain that the arctan was false in some way, although the analytical solution doesn't change much (only rotated in a different way). So the arctan isn't the real problem and therefore neither the initial angle theta. I will try to check my transformation and inform you if I have further improvement. For the time being, I have a Desmos graph that you can play with to see how the trajectories should (normally) act given the certain parameters of the bodies (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2dxd5420lu). Also, very cool website you got there.

Comment: @RektLzz Note that when you say "initial angle theta", $\varphi_0$ in my notation and $\theta_0$ in your notation are both in fact the *angle of perihelion*, as it is in your formula. This is simply because it is the angle at which the denominator is the biggest, so $r$ is the smallest.

Comment: @RektLzz Something is not right in your Desmos calculation- there are singularities, [check out](https://i.postimg.cc/P5bRh1Rh/singularities.png). It looks like (an unsuccessful attempt) for a pair of bodies to swap their orbits. Hm... If this is the case and your desmos implementation is correct and along the given paper, then two body problem analytical solution is unfinished business, because probably it could't define chaotic transitions between orbits.